# Design for separating code and GUI

Tags: java, javafx, playlist

I need to create a Playlist, I want to separate code/logic and GUI by using two classes:

- `Playlist` (code/logic)
- `PlaylistGui` (GUI)

It shall be possible to use the Playlist class standalone, e.g. in some kind of command line environment. The question now is, how would one plug both classes together, when using a GUI? My ideas until now:

- Expose an observable list from the `Playlist` class, create a method `setItemSource(Playlist source)` on the `PlaylistGui` class
- Not sure if possible in Java, just know this from .NET: Let `Playlist` class fire events and let `PlaylistGui` catch them, should lead to uncoupled code? :-)

Open for new ideas :-) Note I am using Java 7 and JavaFX, though I guess JavaFX doesn't limit possiblities, just extends them.

Comment: code/logic part should be an API, such that if you replace the GUI by a text interface nothing (except configs maybe) should change in the source code.

Answer (score 0):

Events in Java:
http://castever.wordpress.com/2008/07/31/how-to-create-your-own-events-in-java/

Other alternatives are:
[Java Delegates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44912/java-delegates)
or both as separate processes with communication via sockets

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at FXML, Controllers and the SceneBuilder tool.

Answer (score 0):

I think your basic concept is sound, delegation of responsibility.

I would create an interface of the model, exposing only those methods you think that any basic controller/viewer would want.  This means you can change the implementation without effecting any of the components that rely on it.

Listeners are, essentially, just a call back mechanism, where interested parties register themselves (through a common interface) to be notified when something occurs that they are interested.

Take a look at [Writing Event Listeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/index.html) for more information.

I would basic start out with a common library which defines the basic interfaces that all parties would need to know out (such as the `PlayList` and listeners).

This would allow to design 'n' implementations of the playlist based on your needs